# What does "pelite" mean, in regards to orthopedics?

Tags: ropa

While in Mexico, I made an appointment with an orthopedic doctor to have him investigate why my feet hurt when I walk on them for a very short time and also in the morning right after waking up.

He examined my feet and told me that my feet were very very flat and that I would need arch supports in my shoes to help with it.  So he wrote me a prescription for arch supports.

I could never find the time to turn in the prescription to a pediatrist so I have yet to get them, but I still have the prescription.  I thought that maybe I could use this same prescription in the States when I return in 18 days.  Currently I cannot afford to turn the prescription in so that was my best guess.

I tried to prepare to translate but I got stuck on the most important area.

"Soportes de pelite".  To the right of it is says LON and ANT, each are marked checkboxes with numbers beside them.  12 for LON and 4 for ANT.

I have searched and searched for the meaning of pelite, but all I can find is definition about sedimentary rocks, which makes no sense... unless the doctor intended for me to have sedimentary rocks embedded into my insole.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found something in a PDF about materials, in Spanish. [Here you can see the PDF](http://www.cpsalud.com/materiales.pdf).

As I though first, **pelite** is a material.

As is described in the PDF, the **pelite** is a type of Soft Polyethylene (literal translation).

I saw in some on-line stores of orthopedics, that you can buy "plantillas de piel" or "plantillas de pelite".

Comment: I was going to add that same link to my answer...

Comment: Searching pelite in Google images gives you a wide view that what can it be, but we found the file that specifies the meaning.